# OpenGL can't send attribute data to shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm able to render a VBO with vertices but when I try adding in colours (using shader attributes) nothing shows up. What am I doing wrong here? I can find a lot of online examples showing this working for interleaved VBO's, but I'd rather use this method (serialized array) instead. Any ideas?

Buffer Generation & Allocation

```
glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
glBindVertexArray( vao );

glGenBuffers( 1, &vbo );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo );

glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ( vertices.size() + colors.size() ) * sizeof(float), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
glBufferSubData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices.size() * sizeof(vertices[0]), vertices.data() );
glBufferSubData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(vertices[0]), colors.size() * sizeof(colors[0]), colors.data() );

/* HERE if I replace the lower block with this top portion, things show up fine
glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, (void*)0);
*/
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 1 );
glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0 );
glVertexAttribPointer( 1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)(vertices.size() * sizeof(GLfloat)) );

glGenBuffers( 1, &ibo );
glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo );
glBufferData( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, faces.size() * sizeof(GLushort), faces.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW );
```

Drawing here

```
glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
glClearDepth( 1.0f );
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

glUseProgram( gl );
glBindVertexArray( vao );
glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo );
glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, faces.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void*)0 );

glutSwapBuffers();
glutPostRedisplay();
```

vert shader

```
#version 130
layout (location = 0 ) in vec3 in_Position;
layout (location = 1 ) in vec3 in_Color;
out vec3 out_Color;
void main()
{
    out_Color = in_Color;
    gl_Position = vec4(in_Position,1.0);
}
```

frag shader

```
#version 130
in vec3 out_Color;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(out_Color, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: By the way (whouldn't be your problem, though), the buffer bound to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` is part of a VAO's state, so you can actuall move the `glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo );` from the draw code into the VAO setup code (well, you're already doing that, just don't unbind the IBO before unbinding the VAO there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the version tag for GLSL 1.30 (OpenGL 3.0), which doesn't support explicit attrib locations, and neither do you explicitly enable the corresponding extension. So maybe your shader doesn't even compile (or it does but the `location` syntax is just ignored). This would explain it working with good old `glVertexPointer`, since if the shader doesn't compile, it will just use the fixed-function pipeline.

So first check if there are any results from `glGetError` and if your shaders compile and link successfully (and if they don't, what their info logs say). But since you have OpenGL 3.0, it's likely you have OpenGL 3.3 anyway, so just change the version tag to `#version 330`, which supports explicit attrib locations.

Comment: Awesome! This was definitely the issue. Can you believe I had filled the entire console with debugging messages, which threw my shader compilation errors way off the screen X_x  How depressing is it that I'm limited to OpenGL 3.0 because of Nvidia's buggy Linux drivers :( but I got this working with  `glGetAttribLocation` instead. Thanks!

Comment: @glitchyme Instead of retrieving the generated attribute index with `glGetAttribLocation` for each and every shader, you can still use your pre-established attribute locations, you just have to assign them in the application code using `glBindAttribLocation` before linking the program. This works since GL 2.0 (and thus since shaders at all).